# Rest api : returned object by server is not the same as the one received on the client side

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jpa

I have a JPA entity, client in which I have added a DTO property (needed in my client side):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CLIENT")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...
    ...
    @Transient
    @OneToOne
    private ReglementDTO reglementDTO;
    ...}
```

My REST resource looks like :

```
/**
 * GET  /rest/clients/:id -> get the "id" client.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/clients/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Client> get(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Client : {}", id);
    ResponseEntity<Client> clientEntity = Optional.ofNullable(clientRepository.findOne(id))
            .map(client -> new ResponseEntity<>(
                    client,
                    HttpStatus.OK))
                .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    ReglementDTO reglementDTO = new ReglementDTO();
    reglementDTO.setDateDeBase(clientEntity.getBody().getReglement().getDateDeBase().getDesignation());
    reglementDTO.setId(clientEntity.getBody().getReglement().getId());
    reglementDTO.setNbJoursCredit(clientEntity.getBody().getReglement().getNbJoursCredit());
    reglementDTO.setTypeReglement(clientEntity.getBody().getReglement().getTypeReglement().getDesignation());
    reglementDTO.setDateDerniereModif(clientEntity.getBody().getReglement().getDateDerniereModif());
    clientEntity.getBody().setReglementDTO(reglementDTO);
    return clientEntity;
    }
```

Everything works fine on the server side, but on my client side (Angularjs), the returned object (clientEntity) doesn't contain my DTO property : reglementDTO). I don't undesrtand why.
Am I not allowed to add a transient property in a JPA entity in order to use it on the client side?

In the front side I m doing this (in my angularjs controller):

```
$scope.clients = Client.query(function(){
                        $log.info($scope.clients)
                    });
```

In each client of $scope.clients, reglementDTO is missing.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: check the network tab, to see what response you are receiving from server.

Comment: Hi, maybe your problem have something to do with the fact that the returned object from the Http request is a promise and your code handling it in the wrong way if you give as an example of the front-end code since you said that the back-end give the required API maybe a code sample will help us point where the error is.